# Understanding particle texture rotation / space

Tags: unity

I want to remake a "portal" that I've seen in RE4. It looks like this:

[image]

I have observed it, and to me, it looks just like a texture rotating on a cylinder.

To remake this, I thought that I should use a Particle System.

First question: Is that a good choice?

In my particle system, I'm using this texture:

[image]

I'm also using a cylinder mesh.

I have then set the following settings:

Duration: 1.0
Start lifetime: 1
Emissions Rate over time: 1
Rotation over Lifetime: Separate Axes: Y: 360

It does rotate on the cylinder as expected, but the texture is really strange.
I have no idea in which way it's being used. Therefore I have added the red, blue, green and yellow dots.

As on can see, the spikes come from above as well instead of only from below.
Also, there's a "gap" in that circle:

[image]

I thought that it was perhaps caused by the texture tiling, so I played around with that. It didn't really help. Here is a [video of my desperate attempt](https://youtu.be/D-7AhrDAUGc).

Can anybody tell me which pitfall I have stumbled over?

If I can't make the texture fit correctly by tiling and offset, what else could I do to make the texture fit perfectly here?

Edit: This is what the cylinder unwrap looks like. I just used Smart UV Project in Blender:

[image]

Comment: How have you configured the UV unwrap of your cylinder mesh?

Comment: I used SmartUV in Blender.

Comment: @DMGregory I have added a screenshot of the UVs.

Comment: @DMGregory Oh man, you're sooo experienced!!! I made the UVs "row-like" (not stacked over each other) now, and now it works. I didn't expect UVs to have such a big impact.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please add an Answer describing the steps you took. I have to ask, though: why a particle system? If you just want one cylinder mesh, without a shower of copies or complicated animation over time, why not just use one MeshRenderer?